# Auto block/ban brute force scanners in Symfony

Tags: symfony, security, brute-force, symfony-security

I am running a web page based on Symfony 2.7. The page uses the `FOSUserBundle` for user management and authentication.

I can observe in the log files, that the page is "attacked" quite often by brute force scanners.

There are two types of scans:

1. Searching for known vulnerabilities, e.g. WordPress files, etc. which result in `HTTP 404` responses
2. Login attempts with default user credentials

I have been using WordPress before. There exist quite a lot of plugins and tools to automatically recognize and handle such attacks: If the 404 request or denied login attempts reaches a certain threshold, the user/ip is automatically blocked for some time. Usually after a few minutes the user/ip is automatically removed from the block list.

**I have not been able to find such a solution for Symfony. Is there any bundle that integrates these functions into Symfony?**

Of course it would not be too difficult to implement this functionally on my own. But it makes no sense to re-invent something that is already out there.

Comment: Use fail2ban, don't implement this on a PHP level. Unless you don't care for your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to block malicious IP's, you should really look into `fail2ban`. [This blogs](https://kalmanolah.net/getting-fail2ban-to-work-with-symfony2-the-proper-way.html) explains it perfectly:

## Creating the Authentication Failure Handler

```
<?php

namespace Your\ExampleBundle\EventHandler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;

class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if (null !== $this->logger && null !== $request->getClientIp()) {
            $this->logger->error(sprintf('Authentication failure for IP: %s', $request->getClientIp()));
        }

        return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

## Add it to your configuration:

```
services:
    your.examplebundle.authenticationfailurehandler:
        class: Your\ExampleBundle\EventHandler\AuthenticationFailureHandler
        arguments: ["@http_kernel", "@security.http_utils", {}, "@logger"]
        tags:
            - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }

# app/config/security.yml
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                failure_handler: your.examplebundle.authenticationfailurehandler
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

## Creating a custom fail2ban filter for Symfony2

To create a new filter for fail2ban, we'll create a file in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/symfony.conf with the following contents:

```
[Definition]
failregex = Authentication\sfailure\sfor\sIP:\s<HOST>\s
```

That was easy, right? We should create a jail in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local which uses our new filter. The definition for this jail will depend on your configuration, but a basic one could look like this:

```
[symfony]
enabled   = true
filter    = symfony
logpath   = /var/www/my-project/app/logs/prod.log
port      = http,https
bantime   = 600
banaction = iptables-multiport
maxretry  = 3
```

Comment: Since the `onAutrhenticationFailure` can be executed with varying exceptions. If all you're wanting to catch is invalid credentials, you can add a condition for `$exception instanceof BadCredentialsException` or `UsernameNotFoundException`

Comment: Link to fail2ban blog post doesnt work anymore

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I think all necessary information is in the answer, so it shouldn't be a problem.